# Vehicle position tracking

Tags: anylogic

I've been trying to track the velocities of vehicles in a specific road, this road have parking lots. This is the code i made to track each vehicle in a certain population, this code is running in a event block that runs every 15 seconds.

```html
for (i = 0 ;i < car.size(); i++){
 if(car(i).isCarOn(road1)){
  car(i).id.setText(String.valueOf(i));
  vCar = autos(i).getSpeed();
  text = text + System.lineSeparator() + "Car (" + i + "):" + vCar; 
 }else if (car(i).isCarOn(road)){
  car(i).id.setText(String.valueOf(i));
  vCar = car(i).getSpeed();
  text2 = text2 + System.lineSeparator() + "Car (" + i + "):" + vCar;  
 }
}
```

the issue is that when a car is changing from road to parking lot, it throws an NullPointerException error, is there a way to fix this issue track the speed of those vehicles? Also it would be great if there is an explanation for this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure your diagnosis is wrong and the nullPointerException is happening with cars that didn't enter the road yet and are stuck in the queue of carSource... 

So I'm asking you.. how are you so sure that the error is happening when the car is changing to the parking lot? I think you just assumed that because you didn't think that there was any other possibility... but I doubt the error is there

Comment: Remember that the carSource doesn't put the cars in the road immediately. They are put in a queue until there is enough space in the road.. but the default values are really weird and the cars stay in the queue even though there is A LOT of space in the road....
Confirm all this before I continue helping

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Felipe, i added a if condition in the start of the for loop if(car(i).getRoadNetwork != null) and the issue is still happening, i made that assumption beacuse everytime that error popup, there was a car changing from lane to parking lot or vice versa

Comment: that's the proof that i'm right :)
The error is what i'm saying and not the fact that the cars are changing lanes...

Comment: But with the if condition that i added, the nullPointerException is still happening. can you give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after your clarifications it's almost certain that the error occurs because the cars are getting into the road too fast and kept on the queue of the carSource.

When cars are in this queue they cannot be accessed as cars even though they exist in the car population... This is maybe weird, but it's how things are.

Now if you want to know speeds in a specific road, you should get the cars in that road:

```
for (Car c : road.getCars(true)){//true means forward lane
    vCar=c.getSpeed();
}
for (Car c : road.getCars(false)){//false means backwards lane
    vCar=c.getSpeed();
}
```

Nevertheless, to continue doing what you are doing, I did a video a long time ago on this topic.. unfortunately the video is a bit long (7 minutes) and boring (I was testing my youtube abilities), but it's related to your problem... it's a trick to avoid problems with this carSource queue: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgYqraEibD4

Comment: By "Car" you mean the Agent? beacuse there is an error "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Agent to Car".

Comment: car is your car class ... normally people use Car, but it seems you are using Agent, so use Agent instead of Car